# onLocationChanged() not called on Android device

Tags: android, google-maps

I have some trobule using Google Maps API on Android.
In onLocationChanged() I create an overlay and add it to the MapView, which works fine on the emulator using Android 2.1, but when I try to debug on a device, nothing happens. What could be the problem?

The device is Sony Ericsson Xperia Arc with Android 2.3.

Thanks, Ivan.

Comment: Probably going to have to show some code to get an answer

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Real devices does not always get GPS signals, especially indoors. I guess you should use `NetworkProvider` in your listener if GPS is not available.

This is a good reference
http://android-developers.blogspot.com/2011/06/deep-dive-into-location.html

Answer (score 0):

Wait for the device get the fix, sometimes the GPS needs more time than usual.

Comment: It gets the fix, because MyLocationOverlay shows current location and it is correct.