# onLocationChanged is not working on real device

Tags: android, location, locationmanager

Now I am working with location based app and my problem is that the location is not updated on the real device. That is the `onLocationChanged` not working on real device. But fine on emulator.

```
    locmngr=(LocationManager)getSystemService(Context.LOCATION_SERVICE);
            loclis =new MyLocationListner();
            our_location=locmngr.getLastKnownLocation(LocationManager.GPS_PROVIDER);
            locmngr.requestLocationUpdates( LocationManager.GPS_PROVIDER, 0, 0,loclis);
public class MyLocationListner implements LocationListener{

        @Override
        public void onLocationChanged(Location location)
        {
            // TODO Auto-generated method stub
            L1=location.getLatitude();
            L2=location.getLongitude();
            String currentDateTimeString = DateFormat.getDateTimeInstance().format(new Date());
            //          Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(), currentDateTimeString, Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
            DatabaseHandlerActivity db = new DatabaseHandlerActivity(getApplicationContext());
            db.addLocation(new Locations_viewer(L1.toString(), L2.toString(), currentDateTimeString));

                        Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(), "New Location   "+"Latitude ="+L1+
                                "   Longitude ="+L2, Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();


            Calendar c = Calendar.getInstance();
            SimpleDateFormat df = new SimpleDateFormat("yyyy-MM-dd HH:mm:ss");
            String formattedDate = df.format(c.getTime());


            ParseUser.getCurrentUser().put("Latitude", L1.toString());
            ParseUser.getCurrentUser().put("Longitude", L2.toString());

            ParseUser.getCurrentUser().put("Time", formattedDate);


            ParseUser.getCurrentUser().saveInBackground();

            //          Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(), "Latitude ="+L1, Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
            //          Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(), "Longitude ="+L2, Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();



        }

        @Override
        public void onProviderDisabled(String provider) {
            // TODO Auto-generated method stub

        }

        @Override
        public void onProviderEnabled(String provider) {
            // TODO Auto-generated method stub

        }

        @Override
        public void onStatusChanged(String provider, int status, Bundle extras) {
            // TODO Auto-generated method stub

        }
    }
```

Please help me.

Comment: Was GPS available? And is there any exception?

Comment: GPS is on and no exception

Comment: I walked around the city and not worked

Comment: What exactly the problem is? onLocationChanged() is not getting called?

Comment: yeah .. its not triggered! :( and it works fine in emulator'

Comment: please print  String longitude = ""+loc.getLongitude();  
          String latitude = ""+loc.getLatitude(); and see what happen in your device.

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/6789569/onlocationchanged-not-called-on-android-device and http://stackoverflow.com/questions/9007600/onlocationchanged-callback-is-never-called

Comment: Have you enabled google location services in your device?

Comment: Check the link below you can find an example and usage.               http://developer.android.com/training/basics/location/locationmanager.html

Comment: @AlexChengalan Have you solved this problem?

Comment: @Akash yes. just look at my answer.

Answer (score 1):

I just used `NETWORK_PROVIDER` instead of `GPS_PROVIDER`. Because GPS is not available in all locations. In my case it solved my problem perfectly. We just need an active internet connection in our mobile.

Comment: GPS is available everywhere as long as you are in open. Where the signal cannot be interfere from something from your sides or above you, like underground, tall buildings, indoors.